# Django - how to fix - request.POST.get returns None?

Tags: python, django, post, django-templates, django-views

I'm learning django and trying to get the user's vote from a detailview. The user chooses from radio buttons and clicks on a submit button.

The detailview's template's form's action is set to a formview url.

Inside the urls I have require_POST on the formview.

Inside the template and a for loop:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{one.name}}">
<label for="{{one.name}}">{{one.name}}</label><br>
```

Inside a form view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    request = HttpRequest()
    vote = request.POST.get('choice')
    return HttpResponse(vote)
```

When I submit the form I can see the choice param in firefox network under post method but the view returns None.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `self.request` instead of your `request` variable.

Comment: It wouldn't ever make any sense to instantiate your own HttpRequest.

Comment: That was quick. Problem Solved. Thanks guys!